# Will I be charged for a VM instance which was in a project I shut down recently?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I recently shut down a project in gcloud. I had a VM instance running in that.

**Will that project charge my free trial credit even after shut down?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with documentation [12-month, $300 free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) where you can find details about free trial.

Than, have a look at the documentation [Close Your Google Cloud Platform Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/close-account):

> As a project owner, you can follow the steps in [Create, shut down, and
>   restore projects](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787#shutdown-project) to delete your projects. **Shutting down a project
>   stops all billing**, traffic serving and shuts down any Google Cloud
>   products within the project. All project data associated with Google
>   Cloud and Google APIs services becomes inaccessible.

In addition, you should keep in mind that accordingly to [Shutting down (deleting) projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) document:

> A project that is marked for deletion is not usable. **If the project
>   has a billing account associated with it, that association is broken,
>   and will not be reinstated even if the project delete operation is
>   immediately canceled.** After approximately 30 days, the project will be
>   fully deleted.

and

> At the end of the 30-day period, the project and all of its resources
>   are deleted and cannot be recovered.

**So, you won't be charged for the project that you shut down.**